# Is it possible to fully get rid the hash on backbone when visiting a URL?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, router

I don't know how to fully explain what I want to achieve but let me fill you in.

I have registered routes on my router.

```
routes: {
    "" : "home",
    "form/:formID/question/:questionID" : "showResults"
}
```

I enabled pushState

```
window.base = '/make/search/';
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: base});
```

When I use and run directly on the code.

```
router.navigate('form/87463636234/question/2', {trigger: true});
```

It get redirected to this URL

```
http://example.com/make/search/form/87463636234/question/2
```

Which is correct. so yeah it all works fine, but the thing I really wanted
When I visit the link from the address bar typing exactly as that, I want it to properly load the page, normally we use the (#) hash to fully navigate with the routes.

This one works:

```
http://example.com/make/search/#form/87463636234/question/2
```

But I would like to make this work when I hit enter to address bar of the browser, getting rid of the hash from the URL.

```
http://example.com/make/search/form/87463636234/question/2
```

Unfortunately now its not, I'm getting an error page.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
After further research, rewrite rule seems to be the solution, however I'm not good on that, maybe can anyone guide me on how to do so. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your webserver to serve your html page with backbone application by all urls including `http://example.com/make/search/form/87463636234/question/2`. If you are using some web framework just configure it to return this page instead of 404 error.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with rewrite rule? when I continued my research, but still no luck doing that.

Comment: What webserver do you use? For nginx see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184959/rewriting-nginx-for-pushstate-urls, for apache - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404567/backbone-js-router-using-pushstate-with-xampp-apache-server-on-localhost